# Assign Associated Record Without Eval (Rails 2.x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

My code looks like this

```
  #     record[field_name] = get_children(field_name)
  eval "record.#{field_name} = get_children(field_name)"
```

`record` is an `ActiveRecord` subclass, and the field in question is a `has_a` relationship. The commented line does not work (though it seems to, but the assign does not take place).

How can I do this without `eval`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more Railsy way to do this, but at least you can eliminate the `eval` by using `send` (from [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999)), which all Object instances have:

```
record.send "#{field_name}=", get_children(field_name)
```